# Passing boolean values to View from C#

Tags: c#

How can I pass the `boolean` value for checking.

Below is my code

Model:

```cs
[JsonProperty("boolean")]
public bool? boolean{ get; set; }
```

View:

```cs
bool test = (ViewBag.boolean== null) ? false : (bool)ViewBag.boolean;

if (test == true)
{
    <button type="submit" id="xxxx" class=""></button>
}
```

`boolean` is store the true or false from Json Api, but cannot call the `boolean` value for checking, any one can give advice? Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "checking"? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? And what does it complain if there is an exception?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read a property out of the viewbag in your view. Please show the code for your controller. You can add values to the viewbag in your controller. And please explain what you expect to happen versus what is actually happening.

Comment: thanks @Alsein, Jonathan.i solved the issues finally, i find that no code handle in controller,so i add the value in controller.thank you for your help^^